# Grayscale not working with LESS

Tags: less, grayscale

I want to use the grayscale function but LESS keeps throwing this error and I don't see a mixin for grayscale or how to use it.  Any help?

```
Error   148 Expected color in function 'grayscale'

 img {
     -webkit-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
    filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
 }
```

Comment: check if you have declared any method called grayscale, try writing the parameter as a string

Comment: How do I write something in less as a string like above?  I didnt find grayscale anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following. LESS is probably not recognizing `grayscale(1)` as a valid function for itself, but also not seeing is as a property value, so that is when you need to use string interpolation to get LESS to compile nicely.

```
 img {
    @filterString: ~"blur(2px) grayscale(1)";

     -webkit-filter: @filterString;
    -moz-filter: @filterString;
    -o-filter: @filterString;
    -ms-filter: @filterString;
    filter: @filterString;
 }
```